# Как вытащить в переменную (и какого типа) выбор цвета из ColorDialog в C#?

Tags: c#

if (colorDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {

```
            button2.BackColor = colorDialog1.Color;

        }
```

Какого типа и как присвоить переменную цвету, выбранного в ColorDialog, чтобы потом использовать для цвета кисти (которая рисуется с помощью маленьких эллипсов).

Comment: @AlekMalek, исправьте код немножко

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Цвет кисти задается при ее создании (передается в конструктор). Если вам нужно поменять цвет кисти, уничтожьте старую (`Dispose()`) и создайте новую, передав новый цвет в конструктор.

Comment: @Flammable, скорее всего вопрос был в том, чтобы передать конструктору кисти нужный цвет из ColorDialog, путем присвоения переменной.

Comment: @Эмиль Сабитов, штоа?

Comment: ..." чтобы передать конструктору кисти нужный цвет из ColorDialog, путем присвоения переменной." 
именно так.

Comment: @Flammable, улыбнули :) 
Есть: SolidBrush myBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Red); 
Вместо Color.Red надо использовать переменную, которая бы хранила выбранный цвет из ColorDialog. Вот как сохранить цвет в эту переменную)?

Comment: И где проблема?

    var selectedColor = ColorDialog1.Color;
    var brush = new SolidBrush(selectedColor);

Answer (score 0):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
 {
    ColorDialog MyDialog = new ColorDialog();
   //Меняет цвет текста в текстбоксе
    if (MyDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        textBox1.ForeColor =  MyDialog.Color;
 }
```

Думаю это то что нужно. Попробуйте использовать такой метод.
Исходя из этого, кисти можно присвоить значение MyDialog.Color.